# How to install i watch application & share data in iOS?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

> I had an iOS application working fine,Now i am planning to add a watch
>   application of the same by adding a new target to the existing
>   application.
>
> I added it and done with UI parts.Now i want to know how can i install
>   that watch kit application on to real device and share data between
>   iOS application and my watch app?

Comment: Installation: You can install watch app from "Watch" app that is available in iPhone. Once application is installed in iPhone that you able to see your app in the list of "Watch" app.

Share data: You can share data iOS application to Watch app using WCsession. Please check : https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession

Comment: If you've correctly added the watchkit app and watchkit extensions to your iOS app, they will install on your paired watch when it is installed on your iPhone.